# Copy and Paste Loop based on Cell value

Tags: vba, loops, excel

Created a macro below thanks to help from another that works.

Basically, it takes the value of the cell in column A and, if a sheet doesn't exist with that cells name, creates it. Then it pastes all rows of data that have the corresponding cell value to that sheet. Ie. if a cell contains the following:

```
column a  column b
dc00025   data value
```

If dc00025 doesn't exist, it'll make the sheet. And paste all rows with dc00025 in A.

This works perfectly. However, I noticed when you run this macro after a sheet has already been created, for some reason it adds thousands of columns dramatically slowing down excel.

To fix this, would it be possible to modify the script to only copy columns b:o rather tahnt he entire row? Pasting them starting at A3 would be preferable but I'm not sure how to fix that.

Thanks in advance.

```
 Sub CopyCodes()

    Application.ScreenUpdating = False
    Dim rCell As Range
    Dim lastrow As Long
    lastrow = Sheets("Data").UsedRange.Rows.Count
    For Each rCell In Worksheets("Data").Range("A2:A" & lastrow).SpecialCells(xlCellTypeConstants)
        If Not SheetExists(rCell.Value) Then
            With Worksheets.Add(, Worksheets(Worksheets.Count))
            .Name = rCell.Value
            End With
        End If

        Worksheets("Data").Rows(1).EntireRow.Copy Worksheets(rCell.Value).Rows(1)
        Worksheets(rCell.Value).Range("A" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp)(2).EntireRow.Value = _
        rCell.EntireRow.Value

    Next rCell
    Application.ScreenUpdating = True

End Sub
Function SheetExists(wsName As String)
    On Error Resume Next
    SheetExists = Worksheets(wsName).Name = wsName
End Function
```

Comment: I just realized I can probably remove the function for adding a worksheet, if it would save memory, as I currently have all the worksheets thanks to having run the script already.

Answer (score 0):

Suggested fix:

```
Sub CopyCodes()
    
    Dim rCell As Range
    Dim lastrow As Long
    Dim shtData as worksheet, shtDest as worksheet
    Dim sheetName as string

    Application.ScreenUpdating = False
    Set shtData=worksheets("Data")

    lastrow = shtData.cells(rows.count,1).end(xlup).row        
    For Each rCell In shtData.Range("A2:A" & lastrow).SpecialCells(xlCellTypeConstants)

        sheetName = rCell.Value
        If Not SheetExists(sheetName) Then
            set shtDest = Worksheets.Add(, Worksheets(Worksheets.Count))
            shtDest.Name = sheetName
            shtData.Rows(1).EntireRow.Copy shtDest.Rows(1)
        Else
            set shtDest = Worksheets(sheetName)              
        End If

        shtDest.Range("A" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).offset(1,0).EntireRow.Value = _
                                                            rCell.EntireRow.Value

    Next rCell
    Application.ScreenUpdating = True
    
End Sub

Function SheetExists(wsName As String)
    On Error Resume Next
    SheetExists = Worksheets(wsName).Name = wsName
End Function
```