# Copy data to another workbook and filter to different sheets based on criteria

Tags: vba, excel

I have written the below script to copy a range of data from one sheet to another workbook based on a set of criteria. I now need to add an extra piece to filter this acceptable data to different sheets named after the values in column G and if the value doesn't already exist to create the sheet named after the value. For example if column G value = JULA then to copy this to sheet JULA however if this doesn't already exist then to create and copy.

```
Private Sub cmdArchive_click()

Application.ScreenUpdating = False
Application.EnableEvents = False
Application.Calculation = xlCalculationManual

Dim LastRow As Integer, i As Integer, erow As Integer

iForm = ("\\Insurance\It\FileData\Computers\Release Note\Collated Release  Records\Master.xlsx")

LastRow = ActiveSheet.Range("A" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row

For i = 3 To LastRow

If Cells(i, 1) <> "" And Cells(i, 9) = "" And Cells(i, 9) = "" Then
Range(Cells(i, 1), Cells(i, 4)).Select
Selection.Copy

workbooks.Open Filename:=iForm

Worksheets("Scheduled Forms").Select
erow = ActiveSheet.Cells(Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Offset(1, 0).Row

ActiveSheet.Cells(erow, 1).Select
ActiveSheet.Paste
ActiveWorkbook.Save
ActiveWorkbook.Close
Application.CutCopyMode = False
End If

Next i

MsgBox ("iForms have been archived, please clear the Team Release notes  ready for the next implimentation window"), vbInformation + vbOKOnly,  "Complete!"

Application.EnableEvents = True
Application.Calculation = xlCalculationAutomatic
Application.ScreenUpdating = True


End Sub
```

Thank you in advance.

Comment: Duplicate: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13943501/copy-and-paste-loop-based-on-cell-value/13944057#13944057

Comment: @TimWilliams so it does! Many apologies, thank you :)

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13943501/copy-and-paste-loop-based-on-cell-value/13944057#13944057