# VBA Cut & Paste row by multiple criteria

Tags: excel, vba

I'm trying to write VBA code to cut/copy paste rows in one worksheet to a new worksheet as long as column H contains any of the values I dictate.

The current code I have works when I only set one value, but I would like the code to execute as long as any of the values I dictate are in the cell. Please advise, thanks.

```
Sub CutPastebyAM()

Dim sht1 As Worksheet, sht2 As Worksheet
Dim i As Long

Set sht1 = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Data")
Set sht2 = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Sheet1")

For i = 2 To sht1.Cells(sht1.Rows.Count, "H").End(xlUp).Row
    If sht1.Range("H" & i).Value = "Laine Sikula" Or "Kim Gotti" Then
        sht1.Range("A" & i).EntireRow.Cut sht2.Range("A" & sht2.Cells(sht2.Rows.Count, "H").End(xlUp).Row + 1)
    End If
Next i

End Sub
```

Comment: *How* do you plan to tell the macro which values to take into account?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Almost there:

EDIT - copying to different sheets

```
Sub CutPastebyAM()

    Dim sht1 As Worksheet
    Dim i As Long, v, SheetName

    Set sht1 = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Data")

    For i = 2 To sht1.Cells(sht1.Rows.Count, "H").End(xlUp).Row

        Select Case sht1.Range("H" & i).Value
            Case "Laine Sikula": SheetName = "Sheet1"
            Case "Kim Gotti": SheetName = "Sheet2"
            Case Else: SheetName = ""
        End Select

        If Len(SheetName) > 0 Then
            With Sheets(SheetName)
                sht1.Range("A" & i).EntireRow.Cut _
                   .Range("A" & .Cells(.Rows.Count, "H").End(xlUp).Row + 1)
            End With
        End If
    Next i

End Sub
```

Comment: Thanks Tim that worked great! Any insight on how I can go about pasting these value defined rows into separate sheets? So for example, v=kim gotti would paste into sheet1 and v=laine sikula would paste into sheet2?

Comment: *Where* are you getting that?

Comment: sht1.Range("A" & i).EntireRow.Cut _
                   .Range ("A" & .Cells(.Rows.Count, "H").End(xlUp).Row + 1)
            End With

Comment: Do you have a sheet with the name currently in `SheetName` ?

Comment: yes I do! maybe this would be easier... I know it's possible to have vba automatically create new sheets to paste the copied content into... can you advise on how I would do that with the existing code you've provided?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13943501/copy-and-paste-loop-based-on-cell-value/13944057#13944057

Comment: Hey tim, thanks for the quick responses, but the code you linked gives the error "Sub or Function not defined" in the first line when debugging.

Comment: That's just an example to show you how to deal with creating a sheet if it's not already there.