# Copy multiple row to another different worksheets based on cell vaue

Tags: excel, vba

I have 150+ categories and I enter data on excel
Now I need your help.
If I enter any category on Column A excel should check if there is a worksheet naming that category. If yes then it should copy the entire row to the next empty row of that worksheet and if it doesn’t find that worksheet it should create a worksheet naming that category and then copy the entire row to the next empty row of that newly created worksheets. Is it possible?
Thanks a million, in advance for your help.
I use this code to copy entire row to another worksheet is there any way to update it so that it meets my requirements?

```
Sub CopyRowBasedOnCellValue()
   Dim xRg As Range
    Dim xCell As Range
    Dim A As Long
    Dim B As Long
    Dim C As Long
    A = Worksheets("Sheet1").UsedRange.Rows.Count
    B = Worksheets("Sheet2").UsedRange.Rows.Count
    If B = 1 Then
    If Application.WorksheetFunction.CountA(Worksheets("Sheet2").UsedRange) = 0 Then B = 0
    End If
    Set xRg = Worksheets("Sheet1").Range("C1:C" & A)
    On Error Resume Next
    Application.ScreenUpdating = False
    For C = 1 To xRg.Count
        If CStr(xRg(C).Value) = "Done" Then
            xRg(C).EntireRow.Copy Destination:=Worksheets("Sheet2").Range("A" & B + 1)
            B = B + 1
        End If
    Next
    Application.ScreenUpdating = True
End Sub
```

Comment: Duplicate: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13943501/copy-and-paste-loop-based-on-cell-value/13944057#13944057

Comment: I sow the code but couldn't figure it out. Its not working in my case. Will you please help me out?

Comment: Copy the code from the other question, try to make it work for your case, then if you run into problems, update your question to add your modified code, along with a description of what's not working, and any error messages you get and which line is highlighted when you see them.  That's how it works best here.