# Filter data in excel and create a new sheet with filtered criteria

Tags: excel, vba

Problem : I have a sheet with 8 columns of data. I need to create a report from this data. The data in column 8 is Green Apple, Red Apple, Blue Apple and Yellow apple. Filtering the data in column 8 (Green Apple) and it displays 2 rows. Is there a way using VBA i can create a new sheet in the same workbook, rename the sheet as green Apple, and copy the 2 rows in that new sheet. Next the filter should change to Red Apple and the data on screen should be copied to a new sheet. Next filter to be changed to Blue Apple and data to be copied in new sheet
Can this be achieved using VBA?

Comment: This question has been answered many times already here: review some of these https://www.google.com/search?q=Excel+vBA+create+new+sheet+for+each+value+in+column+site:stackoverflow.com

Comment: For example: https://stackoverflow.com/a/13944057/478884